# Run a javascript function when input changes using datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found similar topic like this, but none of then solve my problem.

I want to call ajax function when date is picked using datepicker, but it does not work. I've tried many solutions using `.change()` event `.on()` but still cant make it working(its ok when i using keyboard to insert date in input tag).

Any idea how can i solve this problem?

EDIT:
With this functions alert is called when i insert something using keyboard, but not using datepicker.

```
$('#txt_date').on('input',function(e){      
    alert('Changed!')
});

$('#txt_date').change(function(e){      
    alert('Changed!')
});
```

Comment: Post some code and what you tried. Maybe a fiddle would be nice

Comment: `datepicker` as in jQuery UI? or `input` date?

Comment: try this:  $('#txt_date').on('change',function(e){      
    alert('Changed!')
});

Comment: `datepicker` from `http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/`

Comment: @Jen i've tried your code but same problem...

Comment: You should refer to the documentation in the link you provided. It clearly shows an example using `onChange`

Comment: I forget to mention that i create this datepicker using php script, and i cant use that way... anyway thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/ndLp7ggd/)

You can use `changeDate` event of `DatePicker`

HTML

```
<input id="datePicker" type="text" type="text" class="form-control" />
```

JS

```
$('#datePicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true
});
$('#datePicker').on('changeDate', function (e) {
    console.log(e.date);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the using the [.blur](https://api.jquery.com/blur/):

```
$("#txt_date").blur(function (event){
    alert('trigger');
    // Here you can write the ajax call
});
```

Comment: This is when cursor is moved away from input tag... doesn't work