# OnChange event not firing when i use jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker, xpages, lotus-notes

Im making my first xpage site and i have made a bootstrap themed site.
I have an input field that have an onchange event that i want to perform a partial refresh of the surrounding xp:panel.
This is working as intended.

Then i tried adding the jquery datepicker plugin and it seems to work but now the onchange event is no longer firing and the xp:panel is no longer being refreshed - can you help me understand why and how to make this work?

The xpages code looks like this:

(In my faces config i have defined a managed bean Server pointing to the class ServerBean)

```
    <xp:panel id="dataForm">
        <xp:panel styleClass="form-group">
            <xp:label value="Date" for="mydate" styleClass="control-label col-lg-2"></xp:label>
            <xp:panel styleClass="col-lg-3">
                <xp:panel styleClass="input-group">
                    <xp:inputText styleClass="form-control form-date" id="mydate" value="#{Server.mydate}">
                        <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="dataForm">
                            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:ServerBean.updateDate()}]]></xp:this.action>
                        </xp:eventHandler>
                    </xp:inputText>
                </xp:panel>
            </xp:panel>
        </xp:panel>
        <xp:panel styleClass="form-group" rendered="#{Server.showOldDatePanel}">
.... some other xpage stuff
        </xp:panel>
    </xp:panel>
```

When i apply the jquery datepicker plugin like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.form-date').datepicker();
})
```

the onchange event stops firing - and if I remove the datepicker plugin the onChange event works again.

The reason I need the onChange event to fire is that I have another xp:panel which is only to be rendered if the date is more than 2 years back in time.

I dont know what im doing wrong here, it may be a clash between dojo and jquery event handling og because im using the partial refresh wrong or something else

EDIT:

Added the render property to the xpage code and the value mapping - i had them removed earlier to make the code smaller.

The onChange code on the server is here, and it works fine when the datepicker plugin is disabled

```
public class ServerBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7642643485650569816L;

    private String mydate;
    private boolean showOldDatePanel;

    public void updateDate() {
        showOldDatePanel = false;
        try {
            if (mydate != null) {
                DateTime date = getDateTime(mydate);

                DateTime twoYearsAgo = Utilities.getToday();
                twoYearsAgo.adjustYear(-2);

                if (date.timeDifference(twoYearsAgo) < 0) {
                    showOldDatePanel = true;
                }
            }
        } catch (NotesException e) {
        }
    }

    private DateTime getDateTime(String dateTimeStr) {
        try {
            Session session = DominoUtils.getCurrentSession();
            DateTime dt = session.createDateTime(dateTimeStr);
            return dt;
        } catch (NotesException e) {
            //Don't do anything
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getMydate() {
        return mydate;
    }

    public void setMydate(String mydate) {
        this.mydate = mydate;
    }

    public boolean isShowOldDatePanel() {
        return showOldDatePanel;
    }

    public void setShowOldDatePanel(boolean showOldDatePanel) {
        this.showOldDatePanel = showOldDatePanel;
    }
}
```

Comment: wheres your on change code

Comment: it would also be helpful to see the code for the render property of the other panel you want displayed if the date is more than 2 years back in time

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32250588/run-a-javascript-function-when-input-changes-using-datepicker/32254900#32254900)

Comment: Thx santosh, that helped me to capture the change event in query and I used that event to fire a change event against the field.